# Get minimum and maximum date from a column in excel. C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am trying to return the minimum and maximum dates in a column in an excel sheet. 
i have a program that i created in VBA, that i am rewriting in C# and am not quite sure on this part.
The original code i used was;

```
WB.Activate
    DataInputRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.Range("S2:T" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    ActiveSheet.Range("V2:V" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:" & LastColumn & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Sort _
        Key1:=Range("T1"), Header:=xlYes

SYear = Format(WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("T1:T" & DataInputRows)), "dd/MM/yyyy")
EYear = Format(WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("T1:T" & DataInputRows)), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

I have the sort and format area covered, but i cant quite get the "SYear =" or "EYear = " bit nailed down.

Does anyone know a "Simple" way of finding the minimum and maximum value from a column?

The code i have in c# so far is;

```
                            DataInputRows = InputSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
                        Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)OutputSheet.Cells[2, 19];
                        rng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                        rng = (Excel.Range)OutputSheet.Cells[2, 20];
                        rng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                        rng = (Excel.Range)OutputSheet.Cells[2, 22];
                        rng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                        SourceRange.Sort(SourceRange.Columns[20, Type.Missing], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);

                        var SYear = (This is where i need the minimum value of column T (20))
```

GOT IT!!

```
                    DataInputRows = InputSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
                    Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)InputSheet.Cells[2, 19];
                    rng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                    rng = (Excel.Range)InputSheet.Cells[2, 20];
                    rng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                    rng = (Excel.Range)InputSheet.Cells[2, 22];
                    rng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                    SourceRange.Sort(SourceRange.Columns[20, Type.Missing], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);


                    Excel.WorksheetFunction wsf = ObjApp.WorksheetFunction;

                    rng = (Excel.Range)InputSheet.Cells[2, 20];
                    var SYear = wsf.Min(rng);
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(SYear);
                    MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString());
```

Thank you to Ralph for the jumpstart.

Comment: you'd use an excel application class in c#, then use the same prefixed by this eg excel.application x, then x.activeworkbook ? Have you managed any code?  Also, may have more luck posting in c#

Comment: What's wrong with using `WorksheetFunction.Min(` and `WorksheetFunction.Max(` or `Application.Min(` and `Application.Max(`?

Comment: Are you sure it's treating the data in the range as dates and not strings?

Comment: WorksheetFunction only gives me "Equals" or "ReferenceEquals" after the period.

Comment: So @Ralph got me thinking. I was pretty sure it shouldnt be as difficult as it seems, and the commands should be similar enough. so i did a little digging and found where i was going wrong (or more specifically where i wasnt going). edited my code to show the working variant in case anyone needs it in future and +1'd Ralph for the kick in the brain. :)

Comment: Meant to say, @Ralph if you post your response as an answer i can accept it.

Comment: @DDuffy Thank you for the offer. I'd be glad to accept the credits for this. Yet, I don't think this would be honest since you had already the answer within your question when you mentioned `SYear = Format(WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("T1:T" & DataInputRows)), "dd/MM/yyyy")` (which was already the right direction and merely needed some code tweaking). So, I propose that you either delete the question or answer the question yourself (and earn your next badge if the answer gets a score of 3 or more). Thanks again for the offer though. Self-learning is always the best and what we encourage here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @Ralph got me thinking. I was pretty sure it shouldnt be as difficult as it seems, and the commands should be similar enough. so i did a little digging and found where i was going wrong (or more specifically where i wasnt going). edited my code to show the working variant in case anyone needs it in future and +1'd Ralph for the kick in the brain. :)

```
DataInputRows = InputSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
                Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)InputSheet.Cells[2, 19];
                rng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                rng = (Excel.Range)InputSheet.Cells[2, 20];
                rng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                rng = (Excel.Range)InputSheet.Cells[2, 22];
                rng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                SourceRange.Sort(SourceRange.Columns[20, Type.Missing], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);


                Excel.WorksheetFunction wsf = ObjApp.WorksheetFunction;

                rng = (Excel.Range)InputSheet.Cells[2, 20];
                var SYear = wsf.Min(rng);
                DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(SYear);
                MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString());
```